# Can Starfleet return Spock's body to the Prime universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, star-trek-2009, spock

It seems by Discovery Season 3 they're aware of the Kelvin timeline.

Consider the [following](https://youtu.be/aeidTr5PX5w?t=60) from Season 3 Episode 9:

> Kovich : Consider yourself lucky to have skipped the Temporal Wars.
> Among the many horrible things we discovered when weaponizing time:
> temporal travel can make you pretty sick. Turns out our molecules are
> designed to function in the time in which they're created.
>
> Culber: But everyone on Discovery traveled through time.
>
> Kovich: Yes, but only one of you is also from a parallel universe. Yor here
> traveled forward from 2379 and across from an alternate universe
> created by the temporal incursion of a Romulan mining ship. Before
> Georgiou, Yor was the only individual known to have travelled across
> both time and dimensions.

It doesn't seem they're aware that Spock made it to the Kelvin timeline.

If they were aware of Spock's crossover, Georgiou won't be the only one to have travelled across both time and dimensions, correct?

We don't know the details of the temporal wars, but I highly doubt Spock's body would have remained in the Kelvin timeline. Even with temporal accords, couldn't they make an exception to return Spock's body to the Prime universe?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. - Many sources show that the Kelvin timeline is an alternate timeline, for example, the official movie website: http://img.trekmovie.com/images/st09/stotimeline.jpg. Also Yor is specifically said to have travelled from that timeline to the Prime universe.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. While many of us hope everything JJ and minions has done gets scrapped at the earliest opportunity- the sales pitch for the JJ reboot was the old universe was largely intact unlike previous star trek time travel.  The alleged classic universe where Spock looks like Nimoy was termed prime this is where Romulus was destroyed.   Kelvin is the universe where Vulcan was destroyed.   Allegedly prime is where TOS and TNG live but in reality it's where Discovery and Picard live.  Again one can hope JJ and Kurtzman get rebooted themselves someday.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - If Spock prime gets returned to the prime universe, then we can conveniently forget the Kelvin timelime, and if anyone questions where he went, it's classified. Ha!

Comment: @lucasbachmann - This made me remember, does Burnham know what happened to Spock? Remember in Discovery she pulls up video showing Spock talking about reunification, but do they mention that he disappeared?

Comment: I would speculate that Cronenberg would know the Spock Kelvin story but as far as I know the "Yor" story was the first and only time on film and TV that the 2 universes were described and "prime" survived.  Anyone not well versed in the time war would not know in the Discovery universe.  I think a lot of people said Discovery looks more like the JJ verse than TOS so it would make sense to keep anything Kurtzman did isolated from the what I call "classic" for TOS-TNG-DS9. Discovery can be prime to Kelvin.

Comment: I hate to mention it because I don't think the writers are that smart...but the idea that time travel is hard on one's atoms is consistent with TOS All Our Yesterdays where the time travel machine needed to adjust the traveller to fit the time period and it would be fatal otherwise.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - So Spock could have died in the KU because of time travel? (We don't really know what killed him)

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Couldn't they have adjust Yor to fit in the prime universe if they did it with the traveller? It's been a while since I've seen All Our Yesterdays.

Comment: “I highly doubt Spock's body would have remained in the Kelvin timeline” — why?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - After the temporal wars, you'd undoubtedly try to clean up the mess that was created, if you know that you have someone from an alternative universe you now have access to, won't you return them? Even if they're deceased?

Comment: @QueenSvetlana: "After the temporal wars, you'd undoubtedly try to clean up the mess that was created" — maybe? Although there are limits to what Starfleet (I guess that's who "you" is in this scenario) can do (see, for example, the fragile peace with the Cardassians). I'm not clear why whatever's left of Spock's remains by the time the Temporal Wars are over is particularly important to anyone in-universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Regarding comments discussion) All our yesterday's was lost alien tech and the time travel was in the same universe so it may not have been enough to help Yor.  Spock was sufficiently old I don't think anyone would raise an eyebrow over his passing and you are probably one of the first to consider the retcon.  I agree per Discovery Spock was eligible for what killed Yor.  But to answer your original question I don't think the JJ movies knew or claimed the original timeline survived - CBS/VIACOM marketing did to avoid a riot over the reboot.  Thus JJ Starfleet would not even ponder your body return. And any time wars mentioned in Discovery that involved both universes likely would regard Spock as long dead.  So could Spock's body be returned during that war?  Sure anything is possible.   Would they and is it easy? Probably not.

Comment: Ah, it would have been nice if in Discovery they mention his body being returned after the temporal wars.